Why do I get Unsupported protocolTLS after upgrading Apache CXF from 3.5.9 to 3.6.4?
After upgrading Apache CXF from version 3.5.9 to 3.6.4, I started encountering the following exception during HTTPS requests:
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.io.IOException: IOException invoking <URL>: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported protocolTLS
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.checkClientException(AbstractClient.java:645)
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported protocolTLS
    at sun.security.ssl.ProtocolVersion.namesOf(ProtocolVersion.java:292)
    ...

This issue didn't occur with version 3.5.9, and I have verified that the server supports TLSv1.2. My application is explicitly configured to use TLSv1.2, and no changes were made to the code except for upgrading dependencies.
What I’ve Tried:

Verified that the server supports TLSv1.2 using external tools.
Ensured my JVM (Java 11) supports TLSv1.2.
Checked Apache CXF release notes for any changes in protocol or SSL configuration but found no relevant
Confirmed the same configuration worked perfectly with CXF 3.5.9.

Environment:

Apache CXF: 3.6.4 (previously 3.5.9)
Java: 11
Framework: Spring Boot 2.x
Protocol: HTTPS with TLSv1.2

